# Regex to get text between two characters in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've this string:

```
Test 123 ${tag1} lorem ipsum ${tag2} ${tag3; tag4} ${tag5; tag6} dixit lorem ${tag7} dixit lorem ${tag8}.
```

I would like to have a regex to select only the text between ${tag; tag} .

I tried with this:

```
\$\{(.*?)(; )(.*?)}
```

but can't get what I'm expecting.
Any suggest?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the inner text inside the `${...;...}` cannot contain `{`, `}` and `;` use a negated character class solution:

```
\$\{([^;{}]*);\s*([^{};]*)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KKsndO/1).

If the plan is to match word chars only you may simplify it to

```
\$\{(\w+)\s*;\s*(\w+)}
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KKsndO/3).

**Details**

- `\$\{` - a `${` substring
- `([^;{}]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `;`, `{` and `}` (`(\w+)` would match 1 or more word chars, letters, digits, underscores)
- `\s*;\s*` - a `;` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `([^;{}]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `;`, `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/5Agwp7):

```
String s = "Test 123 ${tag1} lorem ipsum ${tag2} ${tag3; tag4} ${tag5; tag6} dixit lorem ${tag7} dixit lorem ${tag8}.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)\\s*;\\s*(\\w+)}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
    System.out.println("=== END OF MATCH ===");
}
```

Output:

```
${tag3; tag4}
tag3
tag4
=== END OF MATCH ===
${tag5; tag6}
tag5
tag6
=== END OF MATCH ===
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is working and the explanation is awesome! Thanks again.